# Laravel authentication with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, laravel

I'm trying to make authentication with Laravel and MongoDB.

The problem is in my controller. This code does not make authentication :

```
    if(!Input::exists('username') or !Input::exists('password')) {
        App::abort(403, 'Forbidden request');
    }

    $credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username', null),
        'password' => Input::get('password', null),
    );

    if(Auth::validate($credentials)) {
        return 'Success';
    } else {
        return 'Failed';
    }
```

But this one just works fine:

```
   if(!Input::exists('username') or !Input::exists('password')) {
        App::abort(403, 'Forbidden request');
    }

    $credentials = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username', null),
        'password' => Input::get('password', null),
    );

    $users = User::all();
    $found = false;
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if($user->username == $credentials['username']
            and Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($found) {
        return 'Success';
    } else {
        return 'Failed';
    }
```

Both controllers are given the same `username` and `password`. First one always prints `Failed`, but second one gives true results.

Comment: I just found out that my model has to implement UserInterface. Doing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Always remember that your model has to implement UserInterface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `Auth::validate` which only checks if the credentials are correct, but does not log the user in. You need to use `Auth::attempt` for a complete login. See the docs here http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users .

Comment: That is not a problem. It should give me success, anyway. I just found out that my model has to implement UserInterface. Doing that solved my problem. Anyway, thanks for reply.